# How to hide a column in dynamic Material table in Angular 6?

Tags: html-table, angular-material, angular6

I have the following dynamic Angular material 6 tables.

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="animalDataSource" matSort *ngIf="animal && animal.length > 0">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let disCol of animalColumns;" matColumnDef="{{disCol}}">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header >{{disCol}}</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let rowValue;">{{rowValue[disCol]}}
            <button *ngIf="disCol == 'Action'" mat-mini-fab class="delete-icon" (click)="deleteAnimalData(rowValue)">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            </button> 
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="animalColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let rowdata; columns: animalColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

And here's my script:

```js
this.animals = [];
this.animalColumns = [];
for (var i in animalList) {
    this.animal = {
        "Id": animalList[i]["_id"],
        "Animal": animalList[i].name,
        "Created By": animalList[i].createdBy,
        "Created On": new Date(animalList[i].dateOfEntry)
    }
    this.animals.push(this.animal);
}
this.animalDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.animals);
for (let displayColName in this.animals[0]) {
    this.animalColumns.push(displayColName);
}
this.animalColumns.push("Action");
```

There are 4 columns in the table. And I don't need the 'Id' column to be displayed in the table. I have tried giving `*ngIf` and `[style.display]='none'`. Both are hiding the column with the full-length gap between the columns.

I could have removed the 'Id' field from the object, but I need the value of the 'Id' column when the user clicks on the delete button[method: `deleteAnimalData(rowValue)`].

Please suggest me, without removing the 'ID' key from the object, how I can hide the column.

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to make it work is by having an array of objects(say animalObjects) that define all the table columns building the template. 
Once they are all defined I have another array that has the name of the columns (animalColumns) to be displayed. 
When you need to hide a column then you can remove the item from the 2nd array (animalColumns) while leaving the first (animalObjects) untouched. 
You basically have to create the table with all the columns, then update the displaycolumn property with the modified animalColumn array.

[stackblitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mohmt5-y88uhq?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

Answer (score -1):

Just do NOT add the `ID` to `animalColumns`, as this array is what defines your columns. See `columns: animalColumns` in your HTML

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The user wants to know how to hide it (and thus possibly toggle it) dynamically. Your response is correct if the user does not want to show a column at all.

Comment: Nothing here suggests he wants to toggle it. He even thought of deleting the ID from object.

Comment: If he removes the id field from the object then the element returned on click will not have the id field which he states he needs. IMHO your answer is correct if he didn't need the id. In this case he needs it so he should have the row defined in the template then remove the id string from the 2nd array. If not he would have then to look for a key in the object returned and  go find it in the data source.  Depending on requirements he may not have another unique key. Easier to have and hide it. Oh, and he said dynamically.

Comment: @AlbertoL.Bonfiglio, I didn't suggest to remove the ID from the OBJECT, but from the columns. The "dynamic" part of the question has nothing to do with the columns either. All in all your answer is exactly the same as mine + code example, so it may be more helpful. However, it's not me that downvoted your answer

Comment: no worries man, maybe i just misinterpreted your answer. As I said your answer is correct. Cheers! It would be nice if when people downvote, they would comment so that we could all learn.

Comment: You're right, it would be helpful to us and the community. Cheers!